# Magento how to apply tax while in product have set Tax class to None

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento 1.9, I have set tax which apply on Sub total. It is working fine.
But issue is in most of products has been set **Tax class** to **None**(instead of Taxable good). So Tax is not applying on those products.
Is there anyway so Tax apply while Tax class is set to **None**.
Thanks you

Comment: please anyone can reply, Thank you

Comment: Hii, anyone have idea that is it possible ?